# how can I combine multiple strings and output a comma between them?

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I will have an input from a web application in the following fashion: 
`channel, income, Country`, but cannot figure out a way to combine these into the following format: `"channel" , "income" , "Country"`

I have tried `str_split` then `paste0` with commas between.

```
test <- c("channel","income","Country")
str_split(paste0(c(test[1], test[2]), collapse = ","), ",")
```

but am getting

```
"channel" "income"
```

ideally the result will have quotes around each string, and commas between quoted strings

Comment: @Gregor, not quite: they want quotes around each string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with

```
cat(paste0(dQuote(test), collapse=" , "))
# “channel” , “income” , “Country”
```

The `dQuote` adds double quotes, the `paste0` inserts the commas and `cat` shows the result without escaping special characters.

Comment: be aware that you may end up with "fancy quotes",  i.e. `cat(dQuote("x"))` produces `“x”` by default on my machine; you may want `dQuote("x",FALSE)`